# Explorer.exe crashing every few seconds

Tags: windows-8, windows-explorer, crash

## The problem

I have been using Windows 8 for a few months now, and today my taskbar has been crashing every few seconds. The taskbar will lose all its icons, then they will all reappear in a few seconds. File Explorer also crashes, however all my programs remain intact.

I've spent the last few hours looking everywhere online, and I couldn't find a solution. How can I analyze and fix this issue?

### Additional information

- This is the error event that got logged:

  ```
  Log Name:      Application
  Source:        Application Error
  Date:          08/03/2014 21:55:33
  Event ID:      1000
  Task Category: (100)
  Level:         Error
  Keywords:      Classic
  User:          N/A
  Computer:      Turtle
  Description:
  Faulting application name: explorer.exe, version: 6.3.9600.16441, time stamp: 0x5265dec8
  Faulting module name: verifier.dll, version: 6.3.9600.16384, time stamp: 0x5215f8f7
  Exception code: 0x80000003
  Fault offset: 0x000000000000abd4
  Faulting process id: 0x2dfc
  Faulting application start time: 0x01cf3b18fa56ab86
  Faulting application path: C:\Windows\explorer.exe
  Faulting module path: C:\Windows\system32\verifier.dll
  Report Id: 5eb78db3-a70c-11e3-8277-8056f2a58ef6
  Faulting package full name: 
  Faulting package-relative application ID: 
  Event Xml:
  <Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
    <System>
          <Provider Name="Application Error" />
          <EventID Qualifiers="0">1000</EventID>
          <Level>2</Level>
          <Task>100</Task>
          <Keywords>0x80000000000000</Keywords>
          <TimeCreated SystemTime="2014-03-08T21:55:33.000000000Z" />
          <EventRecordID>21019</EventRecordID>
          <Channel>Application</Channel>
          <Computer>Turtle</Computer>
          <Security />
    </System>
    <EventData>
          <Data>explorer.exe</Data>
          <Data>6.3.9600.16441</Data>
          <Data>5265dec8</Data>
          <Data>verifier.dll</Data>
          <Data>6.3.9600.16384</Data>
          <Data>5215f8f7</Data>
          <Data>80000003</Data>
          <Data>000000000000abd4</Data>
          <Data>2dfc</Data>
          <Data>01cf3b18fa56ab86</Data>
          <Data>C:\Windows\explorer.exe</Data>
          <Data>C:\Windows\system32\verifier.dll</Data>
          <Data>5eb78db3-a70c-11e3-8277-8056f2a58ef6</Data>
          <Data>
          </Data>
          <Data>
          </Data>
    </EventData>
  </Event>
  ```

  In the Event Viewer there is a 'Event Log Online Help' button which gives a 404 error.
- The `sfc.exe` command did not find any integrity violations.
- I've tried merging this `.reg` file into the registry:

  ```
  Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

  [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\Windows Error Reporting\LocalDumps\Explorer.exe]
  "DumpFolder"=hex(2):43,00,3a,00,5c,00,4c,00,6f,00,63,00,61,00,6c,00,44,00,75,\
    00,6d,00,70,00,73,00,00,00
  "DumpType"=dword:00000002

  [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Image File Execution Options\explorer.exe]
  "GlobalFlag"=dword:02000100
  "PageHeapFlags"=dword:00000003
  ```

  No dumps where created, however.

Comment: If you haven't already, go get the latest drivers for your motherboard, video, sound and peripherals like printers.

Comment: This is my .reg file. Is the Windows Error reporting service running? Also go to the registry and change the localdump folder.

Comment: @techie007 I have updated all my drivers and rebooted but the problem persists.

Comment: @magicandre1981 How would I go about doing that?

Comment: run regedit.exe, go to the key HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\Windows Error Reporting\LocalDumps\Explorer.exe and change the patch in the string **DumpFolder**. Also run **services.msc** and look if the Error reporting service is running.

Answer (score 0):

If you have Windows Restore enabled, try restoring to a previous point. If that does not help
I would create new user or user profile.

As you have also tried `sfc` method, if this does not help I believe the only way to fix it is to reinstall Windows.

Comment: I tried to create a new user profile, but the problem still occurs on the other user.

Comment: I see, did you try Windows Restore or was it disabled?

Comment: Windows Restore was disabled.

Comment: Then I think the only option you have is to reinstall Windows as you have already tried running sfc. Unless anyone comes up with a better option of course, but I very much doubt it.

Answer (score 0):

Exact thing happened to me today on 8.1 laptop.
Problem did not occur in Safe Mode, so I worked my way through turning Services on and off.
Found Windows Error Reporting Service to be the culprit.
Disabled the Service and laptop working now. Might continue to find cause for this service failing.